# How to dimiss the top most viewcontroller only in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a situation like this:

Controller A present ControllerB present ControllerC.

Now I want to dismiss Controller C

But When I call `[ControllerC dismissViewControllerAnimated]`. Both ControllerB and ControllerC are dismissed .

How to dismiss ControllerC only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ControllerB dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or in cases where you don't have reference to the presenting view controller:

```
[ControllerC.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I 've tried these two ways ,and It didn't work ,In fact ControllerC.presentingViewController is ControllerA not Controller B , And call dismissViewControllerAnimated in ControllerB is the same as ControllerB

Comment: ControllerC's presenting view controller should be ControllerB. Need more code about how you set up presentation relationship among these view controllers.

Comment: because each of my controller is wrapped in a navigation controller , maybe this can cause the difference , Let me write a demo to test it first , thanks @LuRui